# Ссылка на объект в JSON

Tags: c#, json

Есть некий проект, в котором пользователь выбирает модификации, по началу вроде все просто было, а именно создал класс, который имел `Id`, `Name` и другую нужную информацию.

```
public class Modification
{
    public Modification(string name)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Name = name;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Проект развивался и стало необходимо следить, какая модификация необходима для другой (зависимости) и какая модификация конфликтует с другой (конфликты). Переделал я класс, добавил в него свойство `Dependency` с типом `List<Modification>`, в котором хотел хранить ссылки на все зависимости. Сериализую в JSON и получаю следующее:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2",
    "Name": "Mod1",
    "Dependency": []
  },
  {
    "Id": "05be1efd-1f66-49fa-8b7c-82704121ce42",
    "Name": "Mod2",
    "Dependency": [
      {
        "Id": "b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2",
        "Name": "Mod1",
        "Dependency": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Вроде 2 объекта, у второго есть зависимость от первого, все бы хорошо. Десериализую обратно, меняю имя у первой модификации, но оно не меняется у той модификации, что указана в зависимостях. Тут я понимаю, что это совершенно два разных объекта, да и вид зависимостей мне явно не нравиться.

Сокращаю сам JSON, оставляю в зависимостях только ID:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2",
    "Name": "Mod1",
    "Dependency": []
  },
  {
    "Id": "05be1efd-1f66-49fa-8b7c-82704121ce42",
    "Name": "Mod2",
    "Dependency": [ "b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2" ]
  }
]
```

В коде я пытаюсь сделать конвертер, но застреваю в самом начале, ибо я без понятия как мне найти через конвертер нужный объект, ибо на сколько мне известно, там все грузится поочередно и нужный объект попросту может быть еще не загружен, а значит мне его не от куда взять.

Единственный вариант, который я здесь вижу, это сделать `public List<object> Dependency { get; set; }`, затем загрузить данные, где в JSON будут только строковые `id` у зависимостей, а потом циклом искать нужные модификации, что то вроде этого:

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Modification>>(File.ReadAllText("Data.json"));
foreach (var item in jsonData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Dependency.Count; i++)
    {
        var id = Guid.Parse($"{item.Dependency[i]}");
        item.Dependency[i] = jsonData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

var first = jsonData.FirstOrDefault();
var last = jsonData.LastOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(first.Name); //Mod1
Console.WriteLine(((Modification)last.Dependency[0]).Name); //Mod1

first.Name = "someName";

Console.WriteLine(first.Name); //someName
Console.WriteLine(((Modification)last.Dependency[0]).Name); //someName
```

Тогда да, получаем два объекта и у нужных ссылки на зависимости, но как по мне это костыли, да и все время тип гонять, ну такое....

В общем, прошу вашей помощи, как сделать задуманное, или я вовсе копаю не в ту сторону и такое делается по другому?

Comment: Нельзя сделать 2 коллекции? Первая - просто массив модификаций со всей нужной информацией о модификации. Вторая - массив пар id1-id2, что означает, что id1 зависит от id2. Получите типичный направленый граф зависимостей.

Comment: Массив модификаций сделайте словарем, когда будете парсить зависимости, ищите по этому словарю и все дела

Comment: Оставляйте второй вариант JSON, но делайте отдельные классы для сериализации/десериализации и для бизнеса. Потребуется очень простой класс для конвертации, который вы будете вызывать перед сериализацией и после десериализации (не во время)

Comment: Типа: надо сохранить/передать — маппим в дто, сериализуем; надо загрузить — десериализуем, маппим в бизнес-класс.

Comment: Такой подход позволит также догружать данные во время работы, например, если у вас уже есть в памяти некоторое классы, вы можете передавать их коллекцию в маппер и он будет использовать их при маппинге вместо создания новых

Comment: @АндрейNOP Простой класс, это средствами JSON.NET возможно сделать до и после, или же как я написал в конце, проходясь циклом? Вообще мне тут надо лишь прочитать данные из файла, не более, сериализовать обратно необходимости нет. Может тут лучше использовать какую либо базу, например SQLite или LiteDB? Правда я без понятия как там подобное все разместить, пробовал вчера LiteDB, но либо получал пустые данные, либо stackoverflow.

Comment: @tym32167 Так это получается тот же код, что и в вопросе (в конце), только не преобразую, а сверяю данные с другой коллекцией, так? Вообще сделать подобное можно, но есть одно но - использовать это все буду не я, а человек, который далек от этого всего и ему проще будет написать id в самом моде, чем искать другую коллекцию и писать зависимости там. Тут либо мне придется его учить, либо писать отдельное приложение для этого (что не очень хотелось бы).

Comment: Проходясь циклом, конечно. Но у вас не будет коллекции `List<object>`, а будет один класс с `List<string>` для десериализации и ещё один с `List<Modification>` для работы

Comment: На каком решении в итоге остановились?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пока еще не определился. Ближе всего наверно будет вариант tym32167, ибо мне надо лишь раз загрузить данные в приложение (тут я думаю перегонять типы бессмысленно по сути), а дальше уже их обрабатывать, правда пока без понятия как мне это все еще и привязать (WPF), что бы потом уведомлять пользователя о необходимости поставить доп моды/убрать конфликтующие, но это уже дело 10-е..)

Answer (score 1):

Перечитал ваш вопрос. Не очень мне ясна ваша проблема.

Допустим, у нас есть json

```
string json = @"[
  {
    ""Id"": ""b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2"",
    ""Name"": ""Mod1"",
    ""Dependency"": []
  },
  {
    ""Id"": ""05be1efd-1f66-49fa-8b7c-82704121ce42"",
    ""Name"": ""Mod2"",
    ""Dependency"": [ ""b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2"" ]
  }
]";
```

И есть класс

```
public class Modification
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public HashSet<string> Dependency{get;set;} = new HashSet<string>();    
}
```

Мы можем это прочитать и сборать из этого, например, словарь

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Modification[]>(json); 
var registry = data.ToDictionary(x=>x.Id);
```

Имея словарь, можно сделать многое. Например, проверить его на циклические зависимости

```
bool HasCycleDependency(Dictionary<string, Modification> registry){     
    foreach(var id in registry.Keys)        
        if (HasCycleDependency(registry, id, new HashSet<string>())) return true;       
    return false;   
}

bool HasCycleDependency(Dictionary<string, Modification> registry, string current, HashSet<string> onTrack)
{
    if (onTrack.Contains(current)) return true;
    onTrack.Add(current);
    foreach(var dep in registry[current].Dependency)
    if (HasCycleDependency(registry, dep, onTrack)) return true;
    onTrack.Remove(current);
    return false;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine($"Has cycles: {HasCycleDependency(registry)}");
```

Вывод

```
Has cycles: False
```

Ну, или напечатать полные зависимости наших модификаций

```
void PrintInfo(Dictionary<string, Modification> registry){
    foreach(var mod in registry.Values.OrderBy(m=>m.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"--------------------");
        PrintInfo(registry, mod);
    }
}

void PrintInfo(Dictionary<string, Modification> registry, Modification mod, string shift = "")
{   
    Console.WriteLine($"{shift}Mod id: {mod.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{shift}Mod name: {mod.Name}");

    if (mod.Dependency.Count > 0) Console.WriteLine($"{shift}Dependencies:");
    foreach(var d in mod.Dependency){
        PrintInfo(registry, registry[d], shift + "\t");
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
PrintInfo(registry);
```

Вывод

```
--------------------
Mod id: b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2
Mod name: Mod1
--------------------
Mod id: 05be1efd-1f66-49fa-8b7c-82704121ce42
Mod name: Mod2
Dependencies:
  Mod id: b8892913-a3be-4ec5-ac09-ee24fd6307b2
  Mod name: Mod1
```

Answer (score 0):

Для соединения "ссылками" данные в JSON нам нужно будет сделать следующее:

1. Сделать интерфейс, по которому мы будем сверять Id объекта и находить необходимые объекты:

   ```
   interface IJsonLinked
   {
       string Id { get; }
   }
   ```
2. Некий класс, который мы зададим как `StreamingContext` сериализатору/десериализатору.
   В данном классе определим метод, который вернет объект по его Id, а также данный класс будет содержать в себе словарь всех ссылок:

   ```
   class JsonLinkedContext
   {
       private readonly IDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, object>> links = new Dictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, object>>();

       public static object GetLinkedValue(JsonSerializer serializer, Type type, string reference)
       {
           var context = (JsonLinkedContext)serializer.Context.Context;
           if (!context.links.TryGetValue(type, out IDictionary<string, object> links))
               context.links[type] = links = new Dictionary<string, object>();
           if (!links.TryGetValue(reference, out object value))
               links[reference] = value = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
           return value;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Теперь нам нужен конвертер для свойств, которые нужно "сопоставить" с их ссылками по Id:
   Тут все довольно просто, если объект реализует `IJsonLinked`, то при сериализации мы берем его Id, а при десериализации (при помощи ранее написанного метода) получаем основную ссылку на объект.

   ```
   class JsonRefConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type type) => type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IJsonLinked));
       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => writer.WriteValue(((IJsonLinked)value).Id);

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String) throw new Exception("Ref value must be a string.");
           return JsonLinkedContext.GetLinkedValue(serializer, type, reader.Value.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Ну и последнее, нам нужен конвертер, который сопоставит ссылку с нужным объектом:

   ```
   class JsonLinkConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type type) => type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IJsonLinked));
       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => serializer.Serialize(writer, value);

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type type, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           var jo = JObject.Load(reader);
           var value = JsonLinkedContext.GetLinkedValue(serializer, type, (string)jo.PropertyValues().First());
           serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), value);
           return value;
       }
   }
   ```

Осталось теперь переделать немного класс, который будет работать с JSON, задать некие данные для теста и сериализировать/десериализировать данные:

- Классы для сериализации/десериализации:

  ```
  class Root
  {
      [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonLinkConverter))]
      public List<Modification> Modifications { get; set; }
  }

  public class Modification : IJsonLinked
  {
      public Modification(string name)
      {
          Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
          Name = name;
      }

      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonRefConverter))]
      public List<Modification> Dependences { get; set; }
      string IJsonLinked.Id => Id;
  }
  ```
- Тестовые данные:

  ```
  var mod1 = new Modification("mod1");
  var mod2 = new Modification("mod2")
  {
      Dependences = new List<Modification> { mod1 }
  };
  var mod3 = new Modification("mod3")
  {
      Dependences = new List<Modification> { mod1, mod2 }
  };

  var root = new Root() { Modifications = new List<Modification> { mod1, mod2, mod3 } };
  ```
- Сериализация:
  Тут ставим игнорирование `NULL` значений.

  ```
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
      NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
  });
  ```
- Десериализация:
  Задаем `StreamingContext`.

  ```
  var rootModifications = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
      Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All, new JsonLinkedContext()),
  });
  ```

Результат:

```
{
  "Modifications": [
    {
      "Id": "66fe811290df4105839a850153116250",
      "Name": "mod1"
    },
    {
      "Id": "1ba03f9480c94a86ba8f2d40e66e95cb",
      "Name": "mod2",
      "Dependences": [
        "66fe811290df4105839a850153116250"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "b936eec3eadb4e38b7f19bd200c0e673",
      "Name": "mod3",
      "Dependences": [
        "66fe811290df4105839a850153116250",
        "1ba03f9480c94a86ba8f2d40e66e95cb"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Для того, чтобы убедиться, что это действительно ссылки сделал простенький вывод имени мода из зависимостей и оригинала, после изменил имя и опять вывел имена:

```
Console.WriteLine(rootModifications.Modifications[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine(rootModifications.Modifications[1].Dependences[0].Name);

rootModifications.Modifications[0].Name = "test";

Console.WriteLine(rootModifications.Modifications[0].Name);
Console.WriteLine(rootModifications.Modifications[1].Dependences[0].Name);
```

Вывод:

```
mod1
mod1
test
test
```

---

<sup>За основу взял [ответ @Athari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13113901/6808809).</sup>

Comment: Какое-то сложное решение, заточенное под конкретную библиотеку, имхо. Я свой вариант имплементировать не пробовал, но, мне кажется, получилось бы проще и короче. Да и без доработок можно было бы выкинуть JSON.NET и использовать вместо него System.Text.Json из NET Core 3, например